# Google places API not showing autocomplete dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am facing issue with google places autocomplete API. It is not showing the drop down. I am getting the response from API. Its just not rendering or appending inside .pac-container in the view. I tried changing the css for .pac-container. But still no luck. I am just using the same code that is there in the code sample provided by google ([Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)). I dont know what is wrong. Kindly help me.

Test link : http://webberspoint.com/test.html

Comment: i tried the same code  from google places api and its working without any issues. Did you made any changes to javascript and html by yourself ?

Comment: did my solution solved your problem ?

Comment: I did not make any change except to put in my key. Also I checked the console. API is enabled

Comment: try to create keys one more time . As you can see , error is related to that only.

Comment: Is it mandatory to get the billing enabled ? I tried the same code on plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/XrSeaQlQxA7kbMNc4KEM and it is working. But not working on server

Comment: Oh looks like they recently changed their policy after June 22, 2016 !! Look at this link https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update#for-apps-created-on-or-after-june-22-2016 . Now they provide two plans Standard and Premium for both of which billing is need to be enabled . Oh man even i did not know it . See it here https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

Comment: Why it is working on plnkr and not on my site. It is so wierd. Breaking my head over this for past two days.

Comment: Man your API keys are different !!! Your API key in plunkr code ---AIzaSyB7EIRpYpVTupWVagU0aZh75YIR79ltmVU . While you API key in your application is AIzaSyDUg-wrdxkY5rmNRj1gQqUbM7CohhqIYNU .

Comment: Use the same API key that is in plunkr code and let me know

Comment: I was trying with newly generated key.

Comment: Disabled all APIs and enabled it. It is working now. Thanks :)

Comment: Yay !!! :) Happy that i could help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution for your problem . When i made calls in your auto-complete input ,a call was being made to google places Autocomplete . But the response returns an error saying `[3,null,null,"This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=_ Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_ For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key"] )` . So kindly check , either you have not activated this API or this API key you are using is not correct . First check , may be your API is not turned on . And make sure , you generate your API for Google Maps JavaScript API . I am also adding a snapshot of the error i received .[image: Error i received while testing you auto-complete]